# Jenkins-DSL deprication warnings on Jenkins 2.x

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Currently I'm using Jenkins-dsl-core:1.43 and Jenkins 1.64.
We are planning to migrate(upgrade) to latest version 2.x in near future.

My DSL pretty much similar to https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example .
Does DSL support 2.x Version of Jenkins?

**UPDATE:**
Downgraded Jenkins-dsl-core:1.42, there is no deprication warnings but some how it's failing to create new jobs.

`Processing provided DSL script
 Example - create failed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Job DSL is fully compatible with Jenkins 2.x. You can probably even run Job DSL 1.43 on Jenkins 2.x. See [Migration](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Migration) for details about migrating to newer Job DSL versions.